# Arrangement of factorial and exponential number in decreasing order

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Arrangement of following numbers in  $(300)^{600},600!,(200)^{600}$ in decreasing order

My progress so far

$\displaystyle e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+\costs $

$$e^x>\frac{x^n}{n!}$$  for $x=n$

$$n!>\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n>\bigg(\frac{n}{3}\bigg)^n$$

for $n=600$  i am having $600!>(200)^{600}$

PLEASE SHOW ME HOW I can PROVE OTHER INEQUALITY

Comment: This is not a rigorous answer, but$$600!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdot\cdot600=\underbrace{(1\cdot600)\cdot(2\cdot599)\cdot(3.598)\cdot\cdot\cdot(300\cdot301)}_{300\text{ terms}}$$Each term is of the form $n(601-n)$ which peaks for $n=300$ and decreases when we go away.     

Only the last couple terms, i.e. $(300\cdot301),(299\cdot302),...,(284\cdot317)$, are greater than $300^2$ and the vast majority of terms in the product are less than $300^2$.$$\implies\underbrace{(1\cdot600)\cdot(2\cdot599)\cdot(3.598)\cdot\cdot\cdot(300\cdot301)}_{300\text{ terms}}\le(300^2)^{300}$$

Comment: May be, you could use logarithms for the first and third and Stirling approximation of $\log(n!)$ for the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{600!}{300^{600}}=2\prod^{299}_{r=1}\frac{(300-r)(300+r)}{(300)^2}$$

$$\frac{600!}{(300)^{600}}=2\prod^{299}_{r=1}\bigg(1-\frac{r^2}{(300)^2}\bigg)<1$$

So we have $$(600)!<(300)^{600}$$